# How to make notification on android schedule by date, month, hour and minute?

Tags: android, date, notifications

I have an application with notification, I want to schedule once every year.. Below my code:

```
private void checkAlarm() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int date   = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month  = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year   = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int hour   = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


          if (date==17 && month==8 && hour==6 && minute==0){
              showNotification(R.drawable.sphere_notification, "hari ini 17 Agustus");
          }
}


private void showNotification(int icon, String text) {
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Hari ini memperingati Hari Kemerdekaan RI", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags  = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.sound  = Uri.parse("android.resource://app.vmh.main/"+R.raw.agustus); 

    PendingIntent facebook = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ShareOnFacebook.class),0);

    PendingIntent twitter = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ShareOnTwitter.class),0);

    Intent exit = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);  
           exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);  

    PendingIntent mainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            exit,0);

    if (Pengaturan.getSetFacebook(this)){
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Kemerdekaan - Remainder",
        text, facebook);

    }else if((Pengaturan.getSetFacebook(this)) && (Pengaturan.getSetTwitter(this))){
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Kemerdekaan - Remainder", 
                text, facebook);

    }else if(Pengaturan.getSetTwitter(this)){
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Kemerdekaan - Remainder", 
                    text, twitter);

    }else
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Kemerdekaan - Remainder",
                text, mainIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(1, notification); 
}
```

I have problem when I implement date and month, notification not working. If I use hour and minute my app is working. 
Can u help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AlarmManager to schedule](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) your task.

Comment: There is no other way by _NotificationManager_?

Comment: No, at least I never came across any. `AlarmManager` do the job quite well.

Comment: I am afraid I don't. However the above link has enough details to implement it.

Comment: @Dewda Yudie If your app worked by scheduling notification through alarm manager can you please post the code. The notification doesn't work for me when calling through alarmManager.

Comment: link was dead when I clicked it